# Why the maze size if I set it to 30 on 30 the maze is 27 on 27?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My main goal is to fill in yellow bricks all the gaps in the maze only on the outer rows/columns.

First , I can't yet find how to fill this gaps but I also noticed that when I select one of the outer bricks the size is 27 on 27 ?

[Maze selected bricks to show the size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKSLI.jpg)

On the top in the screenshot I selected brick that is out of the maze area not sure why and it's position is X = 1 and Z = 29 than on the bottom I selected a brick that is on the outer of the maze and its position is X = 18 and Z = 27 but why z is 27 ? and why there are bricks outside the maze on position 29 on the z ?

The maze size is 30 on 30 in the inspector.

This is the maze class :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Maze
{
    //Grid size
    public int width;
    public int height;

    //Store grid
    private bool[,] grid;
    //Generate random directions to move
    private System.Random rg;

    //Start position
    public int startX;
    public int startY;

    //Public getter
    public bool[,] Grid
    {
        get { return grid; }
    }

    //Constructor of the grid for setting values
    public Maze(int width, int height, System.Random rg)
    {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        this.rg = rg;
    }

    //Generate the grid
    public void Generate()
    {
        grid = new bool[width, height];

        startX = 1;
        startY = 1;

        grid[startX, startY] = true;

        MazeDigger(startX, startY);
    }

    void MazeDigger(int x, int y)
    {
        int[] directions = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        //We create random array of directions
        HelpingTools.Shuffle(directions, rg);

        //We are looping over all the directions
        for (int i = 0; i < directions.Length; i++)
        {
            if (directions[i] == 1)
            {
                if (y - 2 <= 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y - 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y - 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y - 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y - 2);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 2)
            {
                if (x - 2 <= 0)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x - 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x - 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x - 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x - 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 3)
            {
                if (x + 2 >= width - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x + 2, y] == false)
                {
                    grid[x + 2, y] = true;
                    grid[x + 1, y] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x + 2, y);
                }
            }

            if (directions[i] == 4)
            {
                if (y + 2 >= height - 1)
                    continue;

                if (grid[x, y + 2] == false)
                {
                    grid[x, y + 2] = true;
                    grid[x, y + 1] = true;

                    MazeDigger(x, y + 2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the helping tools script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class HelpingTools : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static T[] Shuffle<T>(T[] array, System.Random rg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            int randomIndex = rg.Next(i, array.Length);

            T tempItem = array[randomIndex];

            array[randomIndex] = array[i];
            array[i] = tempItem;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

And last the maze generator script :

And from Line 55 to 70 I'm trying to fill the gaps on the outer last rows/columns but without success.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MazeGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Maze maze;
    public int mazeWidth;
    public int mazeHeight;
    public string mazeSeed;
    public GameObject wallPrefab;

    private GameObject wall;
    private GameObject wallCorner;
    private System.Random mazeRG;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        mazeRG = new System.Random();

        if (mazeWidth % 2 == 0)
            //mazeWidth++;

            if (mazeHeight % 2 == 0)
            {
                //mazeHeight++;
            }

        maze = new Maze(mazeWidth, mazeHeight, mazeRG);
        GenerateMaze();
    }

    public void GenerateMaze()
    {
        maze.Generate();
        DrawMaze();
    }

    void DrawMaze()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth - 1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight - 1; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == true)
                {
                    CreateMaze(position, transform, 0, mazeRG.Next(0, 3) * 90);
                }
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(x, 0.5f, y);

                if (maze.Grid[x, y] == false)
                {
                    if (x == 27 || x == 1f || y == 27 || y == 1f)
                    {
                        var t = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
                        t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void CreateMaze(Vector3 position, Transform parent, int sortingOrder, float rotation)
    {
        GameObject mazePrefab = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        mazePrefab.transform.SetParent(parent);
        mazePrefab.transform.Rotate(0, 0, rotation);
        mazePrefab.tag = "MazeBrick";
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        
    }
}
```

I'm trying to fill the gaps in the last rows/columns with bricks in yellow. I'm close to it but still not there.

Comment: As you have figured out already, you are drawing a 27x27 maze on a 30x30 field. What i noticed is that your `startX` and `startY` should probably be initialized with `0`. Then there might be some issues with the conditions for each direction in your `MazeDigger` method that checks if you are "digging" out of bounds (e.g. `if (y - 2 <= 0) continue;`). I also suggest to rename all Ys to Zs to correspond to the coordinate system used in the screenshot.

Comment: @Random12b3 Where does it drawing it 27 on 27 and not 30 on 30 ? I used a breakpoint on the first nested loop for (int x = 0; x < mazeWidth; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < mazeHeight; y++) it was without minus 1 I added the minus 1 later and I saw that the mazeWidth and mazeHeight are both 30 so why it's drawing 27 on 27 ? I will change the y's to z's

Comment: Your availaible space reaches from `[0, 0]` to `[29, 29]`. Since your start position is `[1, 1]` you are already loosing one row and column. Let's consider only the X-axis on a 10 by 10 maze. Your digger moves to the right/positive x (direction 3) and starts at index 1, goes to 3, 5 and 7.  Now the condition for the next step to the right returns true (`x(7) + 2 >= width(10) - 1`),  although there is enough space to move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the length and width of the maze should be an odd number. So your `Start()` method should increase the size for even numbers.

Think of a repetitive set of two columns, one column of walls and one of paths. At the end of the repetition you need one more column of walls to close the maze.

```
if (mazeWidth % 2 == 0) mazeWidth++;
if (mazeHeight % 2 == 0) mazeHeight++;
```

Since your maze digger puts up the walls and the index of an array is zero based, you want to start to "dig" at index `[0,0]` (or `startX = 0` and `startY = 0`) instead of `[1, 1]`.

Here are your condtions to check if you are about to put up walls outside the bounds:

- Moving down towards negative y/z (direction 1): `if(y - 2 < 0) continue;`
- Moving left towards negative x (direction 2): `if(x - 2 < 0) continue;`
- Moving right towards positive x (direction 3): `if(x + 2 > width - 1) continue;`
- Moving up towards positive y/z (direction 4): `if(y + 2 > height - 1) continue;`

You have to substract `1` from the width and height, because although your size of your array is let's say 11x11, your max index is `[10, 10]`, `[7, 11]` for example would be out of range.

As of the placement of the yellow boxes at unexpected places, your condition  currently adds boxes as a line, where `x` or `y` is `1` or `27`. But these are not your actual borders.

```
if (maze.Grid[x, y] == false)
{
    if (x == 0 || x == width - 1 || y == 0 || y == height - 1)
    {
        var t = Instantiate(wallPrefab, position, Quaternion.identity);
        t.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.yellow;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried. The conditions after the changes and changed the start and end to be 0 : https://pastebin.com/JJSmpSAL than the nested loop to color in the yellow the gaps : https://pastebin.com/8Rnshyxs but the result is not good yet : On the left and bottom its fine but on the right and top its not : https://imgur.com/a/wQA18FT

Comment: Have you commented back in the incrementation of the height and width at `MazeGenerator.Start()`?